# Прыгающие мячи с помощью canvas

Tags: javascript

Как увеличить количество мячей циклом? Я пытался, у меня не получается, сейчас я их размножаю вручную

```js
var Ball = function() {
  this.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400);
  this.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400);
  this.xSpeed = -2;
  this.ySpeed = 3;
};


var circle = function(x, y, radius, fillCircle) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  if (fillCircle) {
    ctx.fill();
  } else {
    ctx.stroke();
  }
};

Ball.prototype.draw = function() {
  circle(this.x, this.y, 3, true);
};

Ball.prototype.move = function() {
  this.x += this.xSpeed;
  this.y += this.ySpeed;
};

Ball.prototype.checkCollision = function() {
  if (this.x < 0 || this.x > width) {
    this.xSpeed = -this.xSpeed;
  }
  if (this.y < 0 || this.y > height) {
    this.ySpeed = -this.ySpeed;
  }
};

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");


var ball = new Ball();
var ball2 = new Ball();
var ball3 = new Ball();
var width = canvas.width;
var height = canvas.height;


/*
for(var i = 0; i < 1; i++){
    var ball = new Ball()

    setInterval(function () {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    ball.draw();
    ball.move();
    ball.checkCollision();

    ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, width, height);
}, 30);

}
*/

setInterval(function() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  ball.draw();
  ball.move();
  ball.checkCollision();

  ball2.draw();
  ball2.move();
  ball2.checkCollision();

  ball3.draw();
  ball3.move();
  ball3.checkCollision();

  ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, width, height);
}, 30);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: Приведите код того, как пытались.

Comment: for(var i = 0; i < 1; i++){
            var ball = new Ball()

            setInterval(function () {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
            ball.draw();
            ball.move();
            ball.checkCollision();

            ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, width, height);
        }, 30);

        }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var Ball = function() {
  this.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400);
  this.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400);
  this.xSpeed = -2;
  this.ySpeed = 3;
};


var circle = function(x, y, radius, fillCircle) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  if (fillCircle) {
    ctx.fill();
  } else {
    ctx.stroke();
  }
};

Ball.prototype.draw = function() {
  circle(this.x, this.y, 3, true);
};

Ball.prototype.move = function() {
  this.x += this.xSpeed;
  this.y += this.ySpeed;
};

Ball.prototype.checkCollision = function() {
  if (this.x < 0 || this.x > width) {
    this.xSpeed = -this.xSpeed;
  }
  if (this.y < 0 || this.y > height) {
    this.ySpeed = -this.ySpeed;
  }
};

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");


var width = canvas.width;
var height = canvas.height;

var ballsCount = 10;
var balls = [];
for(var i = 0; i < ballsCount; i++){
    var ball = new Ball()
    balls.push(ball);
}

setInterval(function () {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  for (var i = 0; i < balls.length; ++i) {
    balls[i].draw();
    balls[i].move();
    balls[i].checkCollision();
  }
  ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, width, height);
}, 30);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: А хоть какое-нибудь пояснение будет?